# In what battle did Maharana Pratap fight the Mughals?

Tags: india, mughals

I have read it ever where that [Maharana Pratap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maharana_Pratap) fought the Mughals for the people of [Mewar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mewar) in today's Western India. Did these fights have historical significance? There is really very less information available on the internet about these fights.

Comment: I think your questions are answered in the wikipedia page you cite which references the [Battle of Haldighati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Haldighati)

Comment: There is tonnes of reference in history books and as Marc says wikipedia is best answer to your question